# placing the results of Get-AzureRmVM into an array and using a loop to add them to the domain

Tags: azure

I need to query a resource group for the number of VMs in the resource group, I then need to run the following command to add each machine to the domain.

In the below example I'm only adding server1 but if there are multiple servers in this resource group, whats the best way of ensuring each machine gets added based on the results of `Get-AzureRmVM`?

```
Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "abcd" -ExtensionType "JSONADDomainExtension" `
    -Name "joindomain" -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.0" `
    -VMName "server1" -Location "uk west" -SettingString $string1 `
    -ProtectedSettingString $String2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `Set-AzureRmVMExtension` for each VM in a resource group, then you could run

```
$rg = "abcd"

# Fetch all the machines from one resource group
$machines = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg

# Loop over each object in the $machines array and add the extension
$machines | ForEach { Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $rg `
    -ExtensionType "JSONADDomainExtension" -Name "joindomain" `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.0" -VMName $_.Name `
    -Location "uk west" -SettingString $string1 -ProtectedSettingString $String2 }
```